# Laser beam focus

Tags: optics, waves, laser

Why isn't it possible to focus a laser beam to an infinitely small point in space? I am familiar with the shape of a gaussian beam, but why can't my $w_0$ be equal to zero?

Comment: Related/possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234996/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/421584/50583, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/140949/50583

Comment: I am sorry, but non of these answer my question.

Comment: The answer is diffraction.

Comment: It's amazing how the two current answers to this question, by _Thomas Fritsch_ and _@ACuriousMind_, answer the question with the same underlying principle approached from two entirely different sides. _Thomas Fritsch_ explains it from the mathematical model, with the result that you'd need a wavelength of $0$ to have a beam with a width of $0$, and _ACuriousMind_ states that at the most extreme case, you'd have only a single wave, which logically would be bounded in width by wavelength and amplitude, thus requiring the same wavelength of $0$. This is why I love physics.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I'm not happy with the answers so far so here's my 2 cents.

Yes $\omega_0$ can be zero. If you have a perfectly spherical mirror with a single particle lasing source inside, then by classical optics it will focus light to a infinitely narrow point at the centre.

The real reason then why it is not truly infinitely narrow (manufacturing defects aside) is that even if we are to ignore entanglement re: the photon and assume it to not ne governed by the exclusion principle, the emitter will be, and cannot be isolated to a infinitely narrow non-moving position.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for!

Comment: That answer is not correct. It is possible to cause a single atom in a crystal to emit light, and to know that the atom is localized to within a fraction of a nanometer, but it is not possible to focus the emitted light back to a region the same size.

Comment: How does that explain why it is incorrect? Uncertainty in location and momentum cause respective spatial and temporal decoherences. These will govern how tightly you can focus light.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You can't focus light into a single point, even if you try to describe it as a classical wave. There is no classical solution to the wave equation with an abitrary small focus-size.

Comment: @Quantumwhisp please tell me then what is the classical solution for ω_0 in my example.

Comment: Just to understand you right - you talk about a spherical wave solution? The spherical mirror you talk about covers all solid angles around the "focus" point?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise any edge would break symmetry.

Answer (score 4):

An ideal Gaußian beam is [diffraction-limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system) - its wavefront inevitably spreads out due to [Huygens' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens%E2%80%93Fresnel_principle). An infinitesimally small beam would diffract infinitely strongly, i.e. not resemble a beam at all: By Huygens' principle a single point (i.e. a "beam source" with zero radius) as a source simply emits a single, spherical wave, not a beam.

Comment: This does not explain why you cannot focus to a point though.

Comment: @PaulChilds I linked three other questions about focusing to a point vs. conservation of etendue in the comments to the question, and the OP said they didn't answer their question, so I didn't see the point of explaining that yet again.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

According to *[Wikipedia:Gaussian beam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Beam_waist)*
the beam waist ($w_0$) and the total angular spread of the beam ($\Theta$)
are related by

$$ \pi w_0 \tan \frac \Theta 2 = \lambda $$

From this formula you see: The wave-nature of light (via its wavelength $\lambda$)
is responsible for the non-zero waist.

That means you would have a beam waist $w_0 = 0$ only for these cases:

- wavelength $\lambda = 0$
  (so that there is no diffraction)
- total angular spread $\Theta = 180°$
  (meaning we have a spherical wave from a point source)

Comment: Or $\Theta=\pi$.

Comment: I think we can assume that the wavelength is not zero in which case the only non-trivial solution is $\Theta = 0$ as The Photon has said.

Comment: @ThePhoton correct, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

The Gaussian beam is not a precise solution of the Maxwell equation, it can only derived in the paraxial approximation, and this approximation is not applicable for small $w_0$.